# Want to give professional looks to a email with ASP.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net, email

I am trying to give the looks of email like this:

```
   This is the looks of my email
```

[image]
Where Right hand side of the email subject is Ignou logo and it is a jpg image.
I have the following class for sending the email and it is working fine:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Configuration;
    using System.Net.Configuration;
    using System.Net.Mail;

    namespace ProductManagementweb.HelperClasses
    {
      public class SendEmail
    {
    public static int SendMail(string ReceiverAddress, string Recsubject, string Recbody)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Configuration.Configuration config =                        WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
            MailSettingsSectionGroup settings = (MailSettingsSectionGroup)config.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");

            System.Net.NetworkCredential credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(settings.Smtp.Network.UserName, settings.Smtp.Network.Password);

            //Create the SMTP Client
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = settings.Smtp.Network.Host;
            client.Credentials = credential;
            client.Timeout = 30000;
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
            mm.From = new MailAddress(settings.Smtp.Network.UserName, "Support Team (Clique City)");
            mm.To.Add(ReceiverAddress);
            mm.Priority = MailPriority.High;


            // Assign the MailMessage's properties
            mm.Subject = Recsubject;
            mm.Body = Recbody;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = false;


            client.Send(mm);
            return 1;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i give the email Format like the image above it is sure that i have to mention the format using html tags but i am unknown where i have to mention and how. therefore any help will surely be appreciated.

Comment: html and inline styles for emails

Comment: How to give html in the code

Comment: I'm sure there are hundreds if not thousands of resources on the internet if you just try googling it.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the html content from your email design in Recbody i.e. email body and change

```
mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
```

to

```
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: when i tried to put HTML  code in Recbody then asp.net will ask to generate the property stub

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "asp.net will ask to generate the property stub". However this way you are creating an HTMl email and the email content i.e. body is what you provide as a string.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to vivekd's asnwer.

You just need to build the HTML in the code e.g

```
string messageContent = "";
messageContent += "<table><tr><td>" + telephoneNumber + "</td><td>" + locationAddress + "</td></tr></table>"
```

Then set the

```
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

And sent the email content to be the `messageContent`

```
mm.Body = messageContent;
```

Obviously you will need to design the layout of the email yourself and build it up by appending to the `messageContent` string.